# SQLite how to setup join in one table with self references to create multiple columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I am super new to SQL.

I have a SQLite table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DIM_Geography 
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    ParentID int NULL,
    [Type] nvarchar(50) NULL,
    Name nvarchar(150) NULL
)
```

The data in it looks like this:

```
    id  ParentID  Type  Name
------+----------+-----+-----+
     1| 200      |town |townN|
   200| 3000     |area |areaN|
  3000| 40000    |prov |provN|
 40000|          |dutc |dutcN|
```

So the higher the number of parentID the higher the rank is and the highest one is always have their parentID as *NULL*, and the lower the number of id the lower in rank it is

I want to get a sorted join view like:

```
   Name1|Type1|Name2|Type2|Name3|Type3|Name4|Type4
   dutcN|dutc |provN|prov |areaN|area |townN|town
```

Sometimes the third or forth or whatever column except the first and the last one is missing and i want to duplicate the lowest rank in missing ones. So it would be look like:

```
   Name1|Type1|Name2|Type2|Name3|Type3|Name4|Type4
   dutcN|dutc |townN|town |townN|town |townN|town
```

So far I didn't come up with any solution at all, because I am really bad at sqlite, except to:

```
SELECT 
    n1.Name AS 'Name1',
    t1.Type AS 'Type1'
FROM 
    DIM_Geography n1
LEFT JOIN 
    DIM_Geography t1 ON n1.ParentID = t1.ID
ORDER BY Type1
```

which only does is order hierarchy of dutcN on top because it doesn't have any parentID

Comment: Do you have max 4 levels of depth?

Comment: actually there are 5 levels

Comment: Usually higher ranked ids have less values than lower ones. What will happen if you want to add a child for id = 1? Also SQLite does not support any pivot functionality, so the number of max levels must be fixed. Any code for max = 5 will not work if you add 1 more level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a bunch of `left join`s with `coalesce()`:

```
select g1.name, g1.type,
       coalesce(g2.name, g1.name), coalesce(g2.type, t1.type),
       coalesce(g3.name, g2.name, g1.name), coalesce(g3.type g2.type, t1.type),
       coalesce(g4.name, g3.name, g2.name, g1.name), coalesce(g4.name, g3.type g2.type, t1.type),
from DIM_Geography g1 left join
     DIM_Geography g2
     on g2.id = g1.parentid left join
     DIM_Geography g3
     on g3.id = g2.parentid left join
     DIM_Geography g4
     on g4.id = g3.parentid 
where g1.type = 'dutc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Allright, with the help of *Gordon Linoff*, i have done it:

```
        SELECT
            coalesce (g4.Name, g3.Name, g2.Name, g1.Name) AS 'Name1',
            coalesce (g4.Type, g3.Type, g2.Type, g1.Type) AS 'Type1',
            coalesce (g3.Name, g2.Name, g1.Name, g2.Type, g3.Type) AS 'Name2',
            coalesce (g3.Type, g2.Type, g1.Type, g2.Type, g3.Type) AS 'Type2',
            coalesce (g2.Name, g1.Name, g2.Name, g3.Name) AS 'Name3',
            coalesce (g2.Type, g1.Type, g2.Type, g3.Type) AS 'Type3',
            coalesce (g1.Name, g2.Name, g3.Name) AS 'Name4',
            coalesce (g1.Type, g2.Type, g3.Type) AS 'Type4'
        FROM 
            DIM_Geography g4 LEFT JOIN
            DIM_Geography g3
            ON g3.ParentID = g4.ID LEFT JOIN
            DIM_Geography g2
            ON g2.ParentID = g3.ID LEFT JOIN
            DIM_Geography g1
            ON g1.ParentID = g2.ID
        Where g4.Type = 'dutch' AND Type4 = 'town'
```

A little comments to the code:

- I repeated in coalesce variables in reverse order to fill the empty columns
- and add another where clause to get the right view for the reason if there are no town in column it would sort it off

As the result the view exactly the same as I wanted in the question.